# A word for eating and drinking, and a word for taking a substance

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that describes act of drinking and/or eating?

And is there a single word that describes the act of taking a substance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most common word for it is [consume](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consume) - to eat or drink something

Try [ingest](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ingest) - it means to take (food, drink, or another substance) into the body by swallowing, eating or absorbing it.

Comment: Thanks; both words were what I was looking for. Will accept tomorrow when It allows me.

Answer (score 3):

I think vickyace's consume is good choice, but another option that works for food/drink/drugs is **to partake**

> 1 (partake of) Eat or drink (something): *he partook of a well-earned drink*
>
> 2 (partake in) Join in (an activity): *visitors can partake in golfing or clay pigeon shooting*
>
> 3 (partake of) Be characterized by (a quality):  *the birth of twins became an event which partook of the mythic*

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/partake